# core.gitProxy and GIT_PROXY_COMMAND appear to do nothing

Tags: git, proxy, tor

I tried to set up a proxy for git (git protocol, not https), using [these instructions](https://gist.github.com/sit/49288). Git appeared to work whether or not the proxy was actually running, which led me to believe it wasn't actually using the proxy at all, and was silently "failing open".

I experimented with the config to try and find out what was going on, as you can see below.

```
$ git config --global core.gitProxy 'touch /tmp/test'
$ unset GIT_PROXY_COMMAND
$ git ls-remote git@github.com:redacted/redacted.git
...
$ file /tmp/test
/tmp/test: ERROR: cannot open `/tmp/test' (No such file or directory)
$ git --version
git version 1.8.3.2
```

How can I get the proxy to work, and be sure that it is working? How can I get it to "fail closed"?

Answer (score 6):

As usual, the problem lies with assumptions in my own question. It turns out that the `git@github.com:redacted/redacted` syntax *does not* use the git protocol, it uses the ssh protocol. So I need to configure the proxy as part of ssh, not git. One (ugly) way of doing that is like so:

```
$ echo 'ProxyCommand touch /tmp/test' > ~/.ssh/config
$ git ls-remote git@github.com:redacted/redacted.git
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
$ file /tmp/test
/tmp/test: empty
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `GIT_SSH` env variable point to a script wrapper with content `ssh -o ProxyCommand='touch /tmp/test' $@`